# "Down for Maintenance" page for Asp.net MVC web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, httpmodule, action-filter

I have the following requirements

- Set a value in web.config and enable maintenance mode
- All non-ajax requests should be shown a custom error page, with the http status code set to 503. The url of page should be retained.
- All ajax requests should be responded with http status code 503
- I should have an opportunity to do some basic logging to a file. Log the url and the user Identity if he happened to be logged into the app
- I am using ELMAH to track/log all unhandled exceptions. The mechanism for implementing maintenance mode shouldn't need me to not use ELMAH
- I have "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" set to true. this was originally done for use with RequestReduce. we no longer use it, but I am hesitant to reset its value to false. I am not sure if any other library needs it.

Once I realized there is nothing built in which supports the above requirements, I felt I had the following two options in front of me (App_offile.html won't work for me).

- an `HttpModule`
- an MVC `ActionFilter`

I dropped the MVC `ActionFilter` as I couldn't figure out how to guarantee it to run before any authentication/authorization filters. I have a custom authentication filter which hits the db. The idea behind the maintenance mode is the db might be offline, yet the web-app shouldn't show a 500 custom error page, but a 503 custom error page.

I wrote the following `httpmodule` and added in my web.config. It works for ajax requests. It kinda works for non-ajax requests. All requests get redirected to the 503 error page. The side-effect is all requests for static content also result in a 503. My error page thus is shown unstyled :(

```
// the http module

public class MaintenanceModeModule : IHttpModule
{
    private static bool _isUnderMaintenance;
    static MaintenanceModeModule()
    {
        var valueStr = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UnderMaintenance"] ?? (false).ToString());
        bool underMaintenance;
        bool.TryParse(valueStr, out underMaintenance);
        _isUnderMaintenance = underMaintenance;
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
    }

    private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var application = (HttpApplication) sender;
        var request = application.Request;
        var response = application.Response;

        if (_isUnderMaintenance == false)
        {
            return;
        }
        application.Context.Items["under_maintenance"] = true; // used later
        if (request.Url.PathAndQuery == "/503") // the url of the action that renders the custom error page
        {
            return;
        }

        const int statusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable;
        const string statusMessage = "Temporarily down for maintenance";

        var requestWrapper = new HttpRequestWrapper(request);
        if (requestWrapper.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            response.Clear();
            response.ClearContent();
            response.ClearHeaders();
            response.StatusCode = statusCode;
            response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            response.StatusDescription = statusMessage;
            response.End();
            return;
        }

        // doesn't work, shows the Yellow Screen of Death (YSoD)
        // application.Context.Server.Transfer("~/503", preserveForm: true);

        // doesn't work, shows the Yellow Screen of Death (YSoD)
        // throw new HttpException(statusCode, statusMessage); 

        response.Redirect("~/503");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

...

```
// web.config
// only the relevant portions of each section is shown

<appSettings>
    <add key="UnderMaintenance" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<customErrors mode="On">  <!-- Custom errors are on, even then I was seeing YSoDs during my attempts -->
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="404" />
    <error statusCode="503" redirect="503" />
</customErrors>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough">
    </httpErrors>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="MaintenanceMode" type="WebApp.Code.MvcInfrastructure.MaintenanceModeModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

...

```
// route config

routes.MapRoute("503Error", "503", new { controller = "Error", action = "UnderMaintenance" });
```

...

```
// error controller

// the authentication filter skips authentication if the allowanonymous attribute is present
[AllowAnonymous]
public class ErrorController : CustomBaseController
{
    public ErrorController(AppConfig appConfig)
        : base(appConfig)
    {
    }

    public ActionResult UnderMaintenance()
    {
        // behind the scenes reads the value from HttpContext.Items. 
        // This was set during the execution of the httpmodule
        if (AppConfig.UnderMaintenance == false) 
        {
            return new RedirectResult("~/");
        }

        Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        // the actual content of the view is not relevant now
        return View("Error503");
    }
}
```

The problems with this approach,

1. Each non-ajax request is responded with a 302 and then a 503
2. The URL requested by the browser is not retained
3. It returns a 503 for all static assets as well

The code I wrote and web.config settings I enabled are all cobbled together from various sources. I am not fully sure what those settings do or what the recommended way is. Please feel free to answer with a completely different method, as long as it can meet the requirements stated.